# Call to undefined method HTML_QuickForm_Error in PEAR package

Tags: pear

I am using pear for form generation. Pear can add element and also get element. But in my case i am adding elements using jquery append method on click of add more button. So when i try to submit my form pears getElement method throws error. Since dom model of my page is dynamically changing pears getElement cannot find that element.Any sugestions ??

Answer (score 0):

[HTML_QuickForm2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2) has support for that [since 2.0.0beta2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2/download/2.0.0beta2). Use this instead of the old and outdated HTML_QuickForm v1.